# PHP codeIgniter: remove element from a two-dimensional column from its id

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, codeigniter, foreach

I would like to remove a question from a two-dimensional table from its id.

I will give an example to be more explicit (with the concerned function that I use).

My function currently gives me the following **wrong result**: 
**I want to delete the question 32 (id=32)**, so I have those lines in my DB column **qids**:

### Initial state

```
**qids**  

+++++++++

10,13,56

+++++++++

1,95,2,45,12

+++++++++

1,32,54,10
```

At the end of the treatment, my DB lines looks like this:

### Wrong actual Result

```
**qids**  

+++++++++

1,54,10

+++++++++

1,54,10

+++++++++

1,54,10
```

But I want to have this in my DB table:

### What I want

```
**qids**  

+++++++++

10,13,56

+++++++++

1,95,2,45,12

+++++++++

1,54,10
```

My function :

```
function remove_question($qid) {

    $this->db->select("qids");         //column name
    $query = $this->db->get('savsoft_quiz'); //table name
    $quiz = $query->result_array();

    foreach($quiz as $value) {

        $new_qid = array();

        foreach(explode(',', $value['qids']) as $key => $oqid) {

            if ($oqid != $qid) {

                $new_qid[] = $oqid;
                $userdata = array(
                    'qids' => implode(',', $new_qid)
                );

                $this->db->update('savsoft_quiz', $userdata);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you were missing the `where` statement. It made your calls to update the whole table. Also, the `update` call needed to go out of the second `foreach`.

```
function remove_question($qid) {

    $quiz = $this->db->select("qids")
                    ->get('savsoft_quiz')
                    ->result_array();

    // Foreach row
    foreach($quiz as $value) {

        $found = FALSE;         
        $new_qid = array();

        // For each id in the comma separated 
        foreach(explode(',', $value['qids']) as $key => $oqid) {

            // Adds still wanted ids to new array
            if ($oqid != $qid) {    
                $new_qid[] = $oqid;                
            } else {
                $found = TRUE;
            }   
        }

        // If the number was found in that row, updates DB
        if($found){
            // Implodes values
            $userdata = array(
                'qids' => implode(',', $new_qid)
            );

            $this->db->where('qids', $value['qids'])
                    ->update('savsoft_quiz', $userdata);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this......

```
function remove_question($qid) {

    $this -> db -> select("qids");         //column name
    $query = $this ->db-> get('savsoft_quiz'); //table name
    $q= $query -> row();
    $quiz=$q->qids;

    $new_qid = array();
    $data=explode(',', $quiz);
    foreach ($data as $d) {
            if ($d != $qid) {
                array_push($new_qid,$d);//push the id if not equal
            }
    }
    $new_row=implode(',',$new_qid);
    //try using echo $new_row;
    return $new_row; //ids after removing
    }
```

Refer the following example..for more

```
 $quiz ="1,54,11,1,54,10,32,1,11,10";

    $new_qid = array();
    $data=explode(',',$quiz);
    // print_r($data);die();
    foreach($data as $d) {
            if ($d != 32) {
                array_push($new_qid,$d);//push the id if not equal
            }
    }
    $new_row=implode(',',$new_qid);
    echo $new_row;
```

Comment: always write ` - >` it as `->`.

Comment: But i have two-dimensional array

Comment: did you getthis array as a string from database?